# Mac OS X Mavericks Changes Default Font of Online Math Expressions Generated by MathJax

Tags: macos, fonts, osx-mavericks, webfonts, mathjax

After I installed Mac OS X Mavericks on my MacBook Pro, an undesirable result was that all online math expressions generated by MathJax, such as those seen in Math StackExchange and MathOverflow, were displayed in a font that looks a lot like Times. I really hate this Times-looking font and would like the OS to return to displaying all MathJax-generated online math expressions in the standard Computer Modern font used by LaTeX. Could anyone kindly explain to me how to do this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Might want to try posting this in http://apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I’m gonna wait and see if there’s a response first. If there’s none, then I’ll post my question there.

Comment: Yeah good luck! I don't have any idea myself..

Comment: @admdrew: Your suggestion was indeed helpful. I posted my question on apple.stackexchange.com and obtained a completely satisfactory answer there. The trick is to disable all STIX fonts in the Font Book application so that MathJax would have to use STIX fonts from its source and not those already installed in my system.

Comment: Future reference for others, [here's the answered version on AskDifferent](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/118180/mac-os-x-mavericks-changes-default-font-of-online-math-expressions-generated-by).

Comment: The alternative to disabling the STIX fonts is to install the MathJax fonts, since local MathJax fonts are used in preference to the STIX fonts (which is used in preference to the MathJax web fonts).  The MathJax fonts are available [here](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/tree/master/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/otf), but you will have to download and install them individually (they aren't packaged for distribution separately from MathJax).